# Changing current directory

Tags: ruby

I have written a Ruby script to install Apache Tomcat on my local machine. When I run the script I am not able to change the current directory to one I want:

```
cmd = "mkdir /usr/java"
system(cmd)

cmd = "cp /home/user/Downloads/file.txt   /usr/java/"
system(cmd)

sleep(2)      

cmd = "cd /usr/java/"
system(cmd)
```

In the above code the `mkdir` and `cp` commands work fine, but the problem is with the `cd` command. After it my current directory is still `/`, i.e. the parent of `/usr` directory.

**Update:** Using `Dir.chdir()` worked, but I am facing one more problem in setting the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables. My code is:

```
cmd = "JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05"
system(cmd)
cmd = "export JAVA_HOME"
system(cmd)
cmd = "PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
system(cmd)
cmd = "export PATH"
system(cmd)
```

Comment: Not relevant to Chef. Can you remove this tag?

Answer (score 4):

Each call to `system()` is run entirely separately from others; there's no hidden shell session shared between them.  (I'm pretty sure, in fact, that they are each run in their own process -- `cd` works, but it doesn't affect your process.)  You can change the directory of your process with `Dir.chdir()`.  You also don't need to put your commands into a variable before using them.  I'd do something like this:

```
system("mkdir /usr/java")
system("cp /home/user/Downloads/file.txt /usr/java/")
Dir.chdir("/usr/java/")
```

Note that there's no need to `sleep()` if you're just waiting for the copy to complete; `system()` already waits for the command to finish.  If it didn't, `sleep(2)` would be somewhat fragile, anyway.

**Update:** With your updated information, it really looks like you'd be better off using a shell script, at least for this part of your script.  You *could* set the environment variables in Ruby through `ENV`, but it would be awkward.  Something like this makes more sense:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /usr/java
cp /home/user/Downloads/file.txt /usr/java/
cd /usr/java/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you need to call it from Ruby, just use `system()` to run the script.  Be sure to set the executable bit, or call it with your shell (e.g. `system("bash script_name")`).

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried system("bash export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05"), but its giving following error bash: export: No such file or directory, why is it.. thanks.

Comment: @itsme Yeah, that command tells Ruby to run `bash`, which is told to run a command named `export`, which doesn't exist.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that, though.  If you're putting your shell commands in a shell script as I've suggested, you wouldn't need anything like that.

Comment: hey can u pls sirect me to some online resources for ruby and chef (system integration framework), as i am just entered the professional phase of my career as a software person.

Comment: @itsme I'd start with your favorite search engine, as well as perhaps the tag info pages here on Stack Overflow.  (Click on the tags at the bottom of your question, then click "info".)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using  `Dir.chdir '/usr/java/'`

Also to view the current files in the irb session, you can do `ls`

Comment: I meant ls with tildes at its sides(` without a shift). I apologize, i was facing code styling issues because tildes in stack overflow assume that the text inside it is a code block.
Though system 'ls' works fine too :)

Comment: Ah, missing backticks, I understand now.  And it's a good point -- that's a very easy way to get a directory listing from within irb, and is likely useful to the asker of the question.

Comment: thanks --, it worked, but i am facing one more problem to set the JAVA_HOMEand PATH variables.

my code is 

cmd = "JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05"
  system(cmd)
  cmd = "export JAVA_HOME"
  system(cmd)
  
  cmd = "PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
  system(cmd)
  cmd = "export PATH"
  system(cmd)
  
this is my first assignment pls help

Comment: @itsme I've added your comment to your question and responded to it in my answer.  Regarding this being your first assignment -- is this a homework problem?